# quick tail on a huge file on linux

Tags: linux, tail

I need to get the last 10 million lines of a 100 million lines file.

```
tail -n 10000000 $in_file>$out_file
```

however the above command took more than 1 day and is still going.
I guess I can use the nice command to assign more priority for the process, but I want to know if there's a fundamentally better way.

Comment: Hard disk or SSD?

Comment: 100 million lines is quite a huge file, nah? Couldn't you have the file formerly divided into some couple of shards? This would certainly reduce the `EOL` searching, thus giving you some speed up. An SSD would also be a great -- darn expansive -- shot (:

Comment: How long, roughly, is each line (or how big is the file in bytes)?  Are the lines reasonably uniform in size, or are there short ones and long ones to worry about?  If the standard tool won't do the job timely, then you will probably need to write your own.  It is exasperating that you'll probably need to scan the tail end of the file at least twice, but probably unavoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from splitting up the file into some smaller files, you could simply open the file and seek it to something you may think of as *close to the end* of the file.

After that, you read as much lines as there may come, and, if you reach `EOF` without all of your 10000000 desired lines, you just need to make a *diff* from the first position you *guessed*, and a new -- prior -- position, and try to read the *n = diff* lines.

I do not actually know if `tail` does so, or if there's any available POSIX tool that performs this kind of operation; implementing this shouldn't take more than five minutes, I guess (:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814069/1655939) may be of some help.